# Memory storage as HEAP OR Stack?

Tags: objective-c, stack-trace, heap-memory

`NSString *myString=@"MUKESH";

const NSString *myString1=@"MUKESH";
static NSString *myString2=@"MUKESH";

NSString *myString3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HELLO"];


NSString *myString4 =[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"HEllo"];`

My Questions related with Memory Heap and Stack storage process?

 1- Which String will Store like Stack or Which one store as Heap?

Thanks

Comment: `NSString` has implementation details that abstract the actual location of the string value from us.  What are you trying to accomplish in particular?

Comment: I don't think it can be on the stack, otherwise the string would be deallocated when you exit from the function where you declared the strings. It is on the heap or more likely in global memory (data section). But you can't know it for sure, it depends on the implementation.

Comment: Objective-C objects are never allocated on the stack.  *Pointers* to Objective-C objects may be allocated in the stack, or in other Objective-C objects.

Comment: The only kind of object that can be allocated on the stack are blocks. None of these objects are allocated on the stack. The easily way to verify is that you can return them all from a function and they won't be broken.

Answer (score 3):

you just don't have the option of declaring an object on the stack in Obj-C... but those aren't exactly heap allocated either...

in the code:

```
NSString *myString=@"MUKESH";
```

The variable myString is a pointer to an NSString... it is allocated on the stack, the variable that it points to is actually not on the heap, but in a special constant part of memory.

in the code:

```
NSString *myString4 =[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"HEllo"];
```

you may expect the value that myString4 points to to be heap allocated, but since, there is a shortcut in NSString's initWithString method, if the string that it is being inited with is a constant string, it will just return the constant string... you can verify that with:

```
NSString *myString4 =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"HEllo"];
if(myString4 == @"HEllo")
{
    NSLog(@"well that's weird");
}
```

but if you did something like

```
 NSString *myString5 =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"HEllo: %s", "Doc"];
```

Then the value that myString5 points to would actually be heap allocated... but really you shouldn't concern yourself with that in Objective-C